# Bubble sorting with linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, bubble-sort

I am writing a bubble sort function to sort nodes in a doubly linked list. My function is very close to working, but I am missing something simple and I can't figure it out.

```
void sort (struct lnode** head, void (*swapPtr) (struct lnode** head, struct lnode* n1, struct lnode* n2),
                            int(*comparePtr) (void* v1, void* v2)) {

struct lnode* next;
struct lnode* temp = *head;
int comp;
struct lnode* temp2;
int count = 0;

while (temp != NULL) {
    temp2 = nodeGetNext(temp);
    temp = temp2;
    count++;

}

temp = *head;
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    next = nodeGetNext(temp);


    comp = comparePtr(temp,next);
    if (comp == 1)
        swapPtr(head, temp, next);
    else if (comp == -1)
        swapPtr(head, next, temp);

    temp = nodeGetNext(next);
}


}
```

When I run the function, It only swaps the first two nodes. I'm guessing I am not setting temp properly at the end of the `for` loop. I have tried a few different things but have not had any success. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you make only one pass on over the list. You need to keep looping over the list and keep swapping until there's nothing to swap. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732610/362938) for an example and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) for the detailed algorithm description.

Comment: Well the comparePtr can return a 0 value as well which means that the node member for the two nodes are equal, but doesn't necessarily mean that the list is completely sorted. I do not believe this will work because of that case.

Comment: For one element yes. But if during an entire pass nothing got swapped then it's sorted. Check with Wikipedia link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using a nested loop since the number of traverses you have go through a list is equal to number of nodes minus 1, that is in worst case scenario. The loop for passes shall stop when there are no swaps done from previous pass (thanks to detunized).

```
hasSwap = 1; /* enable the first pass to execute */
for(i=0; i<len-1 && hasSwap == 1; i++)
{
    hasSwap = 0; /* initially, there is no swap in this pass */
    for(j=0; j<len-1; j++)
    {
       if(l[j] > l[j+1])
       {
            t = l[j];
            l[j] = l[j+1];
            l[j+1] = t; 
            hasSwap = 1; /* the pass has at least 1 swap, if not set, there will be no other pass */
       } 
    }

    printf("Pass %d: ", i);
    for(k=0; k<len; k++)
    {
       printf("%d", l[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Example 1:** Worst case scenario, list is sorted in descending order.

5, 4, 3

*First pass:*

i = 0, j = 0, hasSwap = 1  ->  [5], [4], 3

i = 0, j = 1, hasSwap = 1  ->   4 , [5], [3]

Has swaps from previous pass? Yes, proceed.

*Second pass:*

i = 1, j = 0, hasSwap = 1  ->  [4], [3], 5

i = 1, j = 1, hasSwap = 1  ->   3 , [4], [5]

Has swaps from previous pass? No, but reached the maximum number of pass.

**Example 2:** And this is sorted already.

3, 4, 5

*First pass:*

i = 0, j = 0, hasSwap = 0  ->  3, 4, 5

i = 0, j = 1, hasSwap = 0  ->  3, 4, 5

Has swaps from previous pass? None, stop.

Comment: So in this implementation would I set temp after the inner loop runs? or inside the inner loop?

Comment: It's gonna work, but in the worst case gonna make too many unnecessary passes.

Comment: @detunized thanks, just fixed it :) Please correct me if I'm wrong, I did it myself so nobody corrected me ever since.

Comment: You algorithm still makes `N` passes, but it should rather stop when there's nothing to swap.

Comment: @detunized If N=3, it would have `i=0`, `i=1` as passes since `len-1` = `2` and the condition is `i<len-1`. I don't get it, what do you mean when there's nothing to swap? Thanks.

Comment: dpp, image you have a sorted array of 1,000,000 elements as the input to your code. The canonical algorithm would make one pass and exit.  Yours would make 1 million passes over the array, would make 1^12 comparisons and do no swaps at all. Please see how the [bubble sort works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: @detunized I think I see your point now, it's the optimization that you are looking for, is it not? The code does the job but does not know when to stop. Say the list is already sorted, my code will still traverse the list after the first pass.